# MIcrometer - add list of objects to registry without count

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus, micrometer

I am writing a spring-boot app with a scheduled cron job going through DB to fetch specific `Orders`.
This data should be displayed in a table in Grafana - with data coming from Prometheus.

Is there a way to add a `List<Order>` into the `MeterRegistry` (micrometer) ?

```
class Order {
   String id;
   Country country;
   Status status;
}
```

I think in Prometheus it should like smth like this:

```
my_orders{app="my-api", id="my_id_1", country="DK", status="ACTIVE"}
my_orders{app="my-api", id="my_id_2", country="DK", status="ACTIVE"}
my_orders{app="my-api", id="my_id_3", country="DK", status="ACTIVE"}
```

I don't need a counter cause every single entry is unique.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to add a List into the MeterRegistry (micrometer) ?

`MeterRegistry` stores `Meter`, not orders, I'm not sure what you are trying to do but I'm afraid you are trying to misuse Micrometer/Prometheus.

Especially because the orderID, it seems like a high cardinality tag which will either cause issues in your JVM or in Prometheus (or both).

Here's why: https://develotters.com/posts/high-cardinality/

Answer (score 0):

Skip whole "exposing this data through my app" and misusing Prometheus. And just add your database to Grafana as data source.

This way you'll have chance to query data straight from database into your panels.

Documentation on data sources [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/#built-in-core-data-sources).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom Metrics class for this

```
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Tags;
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OrderMetrics {
  private final MeterRegistry meterRegistry;

  @Autowired
  public OrderMetrics(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
    this.meterRegistry = meterRegistry;
  }

  public void recordOrders(List<Order> orders) {
    for (Order order : orders) {
      Tags tags = Tags.of(
                  "id" ,order.getId(),
                  "country",order.getCountry().toString(),
                  "status",order.getStatus().toString());
      Counter.builder("my_orders")
          .tags(tags)
          .description("My Orders")
          .register(meterRegistry)
          .increment();
    }
  }
}
```

Call the "recordOrders" method by autowiring the OrderMetrics class.